# How to remove required field from nodes

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm displaying jobs in my site but after expiry of last date of application of job, I want to archive it for a month or so and then delete it.

So after last date of application I don't want to be listed in me Menu block and Taxonomy blocks: http://bit.ly/WB59KX . As if the (optional/required) term reference field value has been removed.

In short if Accountant term has been selected in a field( named profession) then after last date of application, clicking Accountant term should not display this node.

I don't want to unpublish expired jobs though.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do this would be to use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to override the default taxonomy listing, then add a filter to the view so that the application date must not be in the past.

Life gets a little more complicated if you have multiple vocabularies and this rule won't work with all of them. [Ctools page manager](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) will let you load a different view per taxonomy.